# ImageCollection (Error) User memory limit exceeded. Mean annual land surface temperature landsat data

Tags: google-earth-engine, landsat, google-earth-engine-javascript-api

I am trying to calculate mean annual and monthly land surface temperature for three image collection of landsat8, Landsat5, and landsat7(image collection of landsat7 and landsat 5 are merged).
The problem is that there is an error:ImageCollection (Error)
User memory limit exceeded, when I am trying to join two image collection with different bands.

```
var filter = ee.Filter.equals({
  leftField: 'system:index',
  rightField: 'system:index'
});

// Create the join.
var simpleJoin = ee.Join.simple();

// Applt join
var thermalband8 = ee.ImageCollection(simpleJoin.apply(landsat8thermal, landsat8EM, filter));
var thermalband82 = ee.ImageCollection(simpleJoin.apply(landsat8EM, landsat8thermal, filter));

print('Joined', thermalband8, thermalband82);

var final_col8 = thermalband8.map(function(img){

  // Create a collection with 1 image
  var temp = ee.ImageCollection(ee.List([img]));

  // Apply join to collection 2
  // Resulting collection will have 1 image with exact same date as img
  var join = simpleJoin.apply(thermalband82, temp, filter);

  // Get resulting image
  var i2 = ee.Image(join.first())

  return img.addBands(i2)
});

print('band Names:',final_col8);


var LSt8function = function(image){
  var LST8EQ=image.expression(
    '(Tb/(1 + (0.001145* (Tb / 1.438))*log(Ep)))-273.15', {
      'Tb': image.select('Thermal8'),
      'Ep': image.select('EM')}).rename('LST8');
 return  image.addBands(LST8EQ)};

var LST8= final_col8.map(LSt8function);
print('band Names:',LST8);

Map.addLayer(LST8.select('LST8'),{min: -30, max: 32, palette: ['white','blue','green','yellow' ,'red']},'LST8');
```

I tried to work on it and the problem is not solved, I need to calculate the LST of each image to use it for estimating the average land surface temperature(annually, and seasonally)

[code is here](https://code.earthengine.google.com/92bea5e18eeeb0b0d3889b507fd046dc)

Answer (score -1):

The main problem was for the joining part of script, I added the NDVI,FV,EM, an the calculated LST to the main collection and used it for other calculation without using ee.list and joining.